# Reset a page to site/feature definition programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I'm looking for a way to programmatically reset a page to that page's site/feature definition, without using SharePoint Designer.  There must some sort of API that can do this, but my Googling around is coming up empty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apparently SPFile.RevertContentStream() is the answer I'm looking for](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1998/reset-a-page-to-site-feature-definition-programmatically).